# Check allowed characters with Reg exp in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a map with allowed characters that should be OK to type.

```
var charMap = {
            "32": " ", "33": "!", "34": "\"", "35": "#",
            "36": "$", "37": "%", "38": "&", "39": "'", "40": "(",
            "41": ")", "42": "*", "43": "+", "44": ",", "45": "-",
            "46": ".", "47": "/", "48": "0", "49": "1", "50": "2",
            "51": "3", "52": "4", "53": "5", "54": "6", "55": "7",
            "56": "8", "57": "9", "58": ":", "59": ";", "60": "<",
            "61": "=", "62": ">", "63": "?", "64": "@", "65": "A",
            "66": "B", "67": "C", "68": "D", "69": "E", "70": "F",
            "71": "G", "72": "H", "73": "I", "74": "J", "75": "K",
            "76": "L", "77": "M", "78": "N", "79": "O", "80": "P",
            "81": "Q", "82": "R", "83": "S", "84": "T", "85": "U",
            "86": "V", "87": "W", "88": "X", "89": "Y", "90": "Z",
            "91": "Ä", "92": "Ö", "93": "Å", "94": "É", "95": "_",
            "96": "é", "97": "a", "98": "b", "99": "c", "100": "d",
            "101": "e", "102": "f", "103": "g", "104": "h", "105": "i",
            "106": "j", "107": "k", "108": "l", "109": "m", "110": "n",
            "111": "o", "112": "p", "113": "q", "114": "r", "115": "s",
            "116": "t", "117": "u", "118": "v", "119": "w", "120": "x",
            "121": "y", "122": "z", "123": "ä", "124": "ö", "125": "å",
            "126": "€", "127": "£"
        };
```

Here is all the characters as a string: `!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÅÉ_éabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöå€£` and a space.

I'm trying to write a reg exp test, but my code always returns false for any input (I guess I'm screwing up some escape characters. This is my code:

```
var checkAllCharachters = function (str) {
        var allowedCharacters = new RegExp(/^[!"#$%&'\(\)\*+,\-.\/\d:;<=>?@\\sA-ZÄÖÅÉ_éa-zäöå€£\\n]*$/);

        if(allowedCharacters.test(str)){
            console.log("contained characters thats not allowed");
        }
    }
```

[A small JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xsee9x6v/6/) does not work with space. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: One I can see in first glance is `$` which should be escaped otherwise it will be treated as end of line. And, you also need to include everything within square brackets `[...]`.

Comment: You failed to create a *cahracter class*. Put all inside `[...]`, add a `*` after it, remove `g`, enclose the pattern with `^` and `$`. Escape the hyphen in the character class. And remove `new RegExp()`, just use a regex literal notation.

Comment: The one you missed to escape, by the way, is `.` - it matches *any* character. But @Wiktor is right, you are checking against your full string only.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xsee9x6v/6/ space is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make a character set or class with `[` and `]` (don't forget to escape the hyphen) and surround it with the `^` and `$` to denote the entire string. You also don't need to call the `RegExp` constructor since you have a literal. And you also need to say 0 or more or 1 or more.

```
var checkAllCharachters = function (str) {
    var allowedCharacters = /^[!"#$%&'\(\)\*+,\-.\/\d:;<=>?@A-ZÄÖÅÉ_éa-zäöå€£ ]*$/g;
    if(allowedCharacters.test(str)){
        console.log("contained characters thats not allowed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, without a quantifier, it will only match 1 char strings. And the `/g` with `test` will produce weird results.

Answer (score 1):

This is more compact:

```
[!"#$%&'()*+,-./0-9:;<=>?@A-ZÄÖÅÉ_éa-zäöå€£]
```

Comment: You forgot `0-9 -> \d`

Comment: `A-Za-z0-9_` can be replaced with a single `\w`.

Comment: I forgot to add \s inside brackets

Comment: @RadLexus \w can include '_' char, which is not in the list

Comment: ?? But it is: `"91": "Ä", "92": "Ö", "93": "Å", "94": "É", "95": "_",`. It's also in *your* list, right there between `É` and `é`.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is not really needed to check whether the typed character is ok or not. The only thing you need to do is;

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
  var charCode = evt.keyCode || evt.which,
          char = String.fromCharCode(charCode),
      passList = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZÄÖÅÉ_éabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzäöå€£";
  !!~passList.indexOf(char) && do something;
};
```